# Setting up a golang API that queries a database every hour to refresh its data

Tags: rest, go, asynchronous

I'm relatively new to golang and could use some high-level tips on how to structure this. I'm trying to a build a REST API:

- The user would provide a small JSON payload via POST method
- The API compares the user’s input data against a reference dataset stored as a slice of structs and calculates a value
- This value is returned to the user
- Every hour a database is queried to and replaces the slice of structs dataset with another slice of structs dataset. Basically this refreshes the reference data
- I'd like this refreshing job to be async so it doesn't slow down the user experience

I'm using the golang's Echo framework (https://echo.labstack.com/). Here is my attempt in golang-like pseudocode.
How would you structure this API to refresh the data hourly async?

To clarify, the part Im stuck on is the “query the DB every hour async in the background” bit. Im unsure how to do that in thos scenario.

```
func main() {

    e := echo.New()
    e.POST("/", func(something) {
        
        // This func queries the DB and saves reference dataset result as a slice of structs
        dataset := refreshDB() 

        // Does some calculations on input JSON data and reference dataset
        result := doCalcs(inputJSON, dataset)

        // Prep response in neat JSON
        responseForUser := prepOutput(result)

        return responseForUser
    
    })
    
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For async code in Go you can use a [goroutine](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Go_statements), to execute the code periodically you can use a [ticker](https://pkg.go.dev/time#Ticker).

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "time"
    "sync"
)

var rwm sync.RWMutex
var sliceOfStructs []struct{/* ... */}

func main() {
    go func() {
        tick := time.NewTicker(time.Hour)
        for range tick.C {
            rwm.Lock()
            sliceOfStructs = []struct{}{ /* refresh with new data */ }
            rwm.Unlock()
        }
    }()
    
    // start server
}
```

- If `sliceOfStructs` needs to be accessible across multiple packages then you'll need to export it and move it to a non-main package, i.e. one that can be imported. And do the same for `rwm`.
- Make sure that any code that reads `sliceOfStructs` invokes `rwm.RLock` before reading and `rwm.RUnlock` when done.
- If you have more than one goroutine that needs to write `sliceOfStructs` then you should change `rwm` from `sync.RWMutex` to `sync.Mutex`.

Comment: It sounds like this "ticker" concept is exactly what I was looking for. A cron-like sort of functionality in go.

Comment: @Slyron `time.Ticker` is good enough for simple stuff, but if you ever need real cron functionality in Go you can go to github and choose one of a number of implementations. The [robfig/cron package](https://github.com/robfig/cron) is a good example.